# Convert a list of list to list of Maps with a value

Tags: json, transform, jolt

I am trying to convert the folowing input to the desired output using Jolt

```
[
  {
    "scores": [
      [
        4,
        1
      ],
      [
        2,
        1
      ],
      [
        8,
        5
      ],
      [
        7,
        3
      ],
      [
        5,
        10
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired Output

```
[
  {
    "value1": 4,
    "value2": 1
  },
  {
    "value1": 2,
    "value2": 1
  },
  {
    "value1": 8,
    "value2": 5
  },
  {
    "value1": 7,
    "value2": 3
  },
  {
    "value1": 5,
    "value2": 10
  }
]
```

I want to convert the list of list to the map. The elements in the input list should be the values of the keys.

Can anyone help with the Jolt Spec.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec which incurs  indexes **`0`** and **`1`** respectively as looping through in the scores array it such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "scores": {          
          "*": {
            "0": "[&1].value1", // the first component of the subarray
            "1": "[&1].value2"  // the second component of the subarray
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: I have a follow-up question on this.
What if we have two maps in the first list?

Comment: Yes, I asked a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75965881/convert-a-list-of-list-to-a-list-of-maps

Comment: Would really like to know your thoughts on the question :)

Comment: Yes, It works and gives the desired output.
Thank you so much.