# Convert a list of list to a list of maps

Tags: json, transform, jolt

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75960736/convert-a-list-of-list-to-list-of-maps-with-a-value) and got the answer, but have another version of the input.

Here is another version of the **input**:

```json
[
  {"scores":[[4,1],[2,1],[8,5],[7,3],[5,10]]},
  {"scores":[[23,33],[20,11],[84,59],[72,35],[55,1]]}
]
```

Here is the **desired output**:

```json
[
  {"value1":4,"value2":1},
  {"value1":2,"value2":1},
  {"value1":8,"value2":5},
  {"value1":7,"value2":3},
  {"value1":5,"value2":10},
  {"value1":23,"value2":33},
  {"value1":20,"value2":11},
  {"value1":84,"value2":59},
  {"value1":72,"value2":35},
  {"value1":55,"value2":1}
]
```

The input now has two maps with a list named scores, I require the output to be the same level.

Please help with the Jolt spec.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried changing the level but didn't help.

Comment: I edited to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "0": "[&3][&1].value1",
            "1": "[&3][&1].value2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mohammad.
I will accept this as the answer.